# cleditor.selectedHTML(): object doesn't support property or method

Tags: cleditor

I'm using the cleditor on a page to create a RTE box with a Save and Cancel button below it.

In my "onclick" function for the Save button.  I call two methods of the cleditor object, namely: .select() and .selectedHTML()

The .select() works fine but the .selectedHTML() yields a "object doesn't support property or method" error in my browser (ie).

Why am I getting this error?  The .selectedHTML() method does exist.

See Code below:

```
var $editor
uab.crs_sum.prototype.render = function() {

    var oJSON = {};
    var target = this.getTarget();
    var tmpHTML = [];
    var chkOption = "";

tmpHTML = ["<textarea id='input' name='input'>This is some really great Content</textarea>"];
tmpHTML.push("<div><button style='width:6em'type='button' onclick='cancelEdit();'>Cancel</button><span style='width:3em'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span><button style='width:6em' type='button' onclick='saveEdit();'>Save</button></div>"); 
target.innerHTML = tmpHTML.join("");

$editor = $("#input").cleditor({
      "width":"100%"
      });
}


function saveEdit() {
    $editor.select();
    alert($editor.selectedHTML());  // Error occurs on this line 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `.selectedHTML()` method but what has worked with me is to just use the standard jQuery `.val()` method. And just store a working copy to revert back to.

```
var $element = $('#input'),
    currentVal = $element.val();

$editor = $element.cleditor({
      "width":"100%"
 })[0];


function saveEdit() {
    alert($element.val());
}

function cancelEdit() {
  $element.val(currentVal);
  $editor.updateFrame();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ran into the same problem with trying to use selectedHTML() the following change fixed my issue.

```
$('#input').cleditor()[0].selectedHTML()
```

It looks like the cleditor() function returns an array. I've only tried this with a single editor on the page.